# Android close activity after thread ends

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an activity, and a buttonClick where I call a Thread that will POST some JSON to a PHP file. I want the activity to get Closed after the thread ends. How can I do that?

This is my click event:

```
Button bsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    View.OnClickListener eventHandlerx = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                       sendJson( urlx, jsonarray);
                    }
    ...
```

And this is my Thread:

```
private void sendJson(final String urlx, final JSONArray jsonarray) {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        ...}
    ...}
}
```

Where can I call finish() in order to close my activity?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can call `finish()` from anywhere within the UI thread. You can execute code from within the UI thread by using an [`AysncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)'s [`onPostExecute`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) (replace your `Thread` with it) or by starting a `Runnable` using the `Activity`'s [`runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Comment: So, using Thread there is no way to finish the current activity?

Comment: I just updated the answer to be a bit more clear. You can only call finish from an UI thread, as it messes with the UI. It might work, but it is not stated anywhere that it is safe to finish an activity from another thread.

Comment: Side note: `AsyncTask` is the recommended way to do what you're doing, as it wraps all the thread safety stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will help

```
   class SendJson extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    //here you can call functionality

    }        

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {            
    //here you can call finish 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using Handler since you just want to close the activity:

```
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //do your stuff here

            MyActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
```

But as @dst mentioned, you should use `AsyncTask` whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

I did tests
- you can startActivity from non-ui Thread
- you can finish Activity from non-ui Thread

Look at the ACRA project - nice exception handling. In ReportExecutor in line 251 (https://github.com/ACRA/acra/blob/master/src/main/java/org/acra/builder/ReportExecutor.java#L251) activity is started in new thread.

I was too surprised why it is working :)